# Install Chrome Extension from Mac App

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

want to install chrome extension when mac app is installed.
i followed the instructions on the developer site of chrome [Other Deployment Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)

Tried both the methods

1. Local file url

Created file external_extensions.json at path /Users/Sadiq/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions with contents

```
 {
"external_crx": "/home/share/extension.crx",
"external_version": "1.0"
 }
```

But when i restarted chrome the extension at that path is not installed on chrome.

2. Store Installation:

Created file fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop.json at path
/Users/Sadiq/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions

with contents

```
{
 "fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop": {
 "external_update_url": "http://test.com/extension_info.xml"
 }
}
```

Created extension_info.xml file at hosting with following code

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
 <app appid='fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop'>
 <updatecheck     codebase='https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/blobs/QgAAAC6zw0qH2D    JtnXe8Z7rUJP0d-cjv-    4fr0OfD1rZlXmwxm1zzQqbU1RRtbPRUspFh5VJIFInV7jQnzNI5Ax7-tVFFNKUqiQdoiA-    43Tdd46i1AMZSmuUS-XRXhbdPB5d5cMLUhLCthCuF7g/extension_1_0_0_26.crx'     version='1.0.0.26' />
 </app>
 </gupdate>
```

But when i relaunch the chrome it must install the extension given in the manefest file .At first time it works but when i uninstall the extension and relaunch the browser it doesn't install it again. no oter changes are done

I want to install firefox extension on my mac app install .

Thanks

Sadiq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At first time it works but when i uninstall the extension and relaunch the browser it doesn't install it again.

This is intentional. When programmatically installed extension is uninstalled by the user, it becomes *blacklisted* and will not trigger installation again.

The user can still manually install it from the store, but there's nothing you can do if it was denied.

Comment: Good .how would i remove item in blacklist on mac

Comment: Quoting the documentation: _"If the user uninstalls your extension, you should respect that decision. However, if you (the developer) accidentally uninstalled your extension through the UI, you can remove the blacklist tag by installing the extension normally through the UI, and then uninstalling it."_ So basically install the extension through the Web Store interface.

Comment: And for testing purposes, it's best to launch Chrome with a fresh profile. Blacklists are per profile.